# variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c

Estou a ter um erro quando peço na linha de comando os valores de WORLD X e WORLD Y

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
>        AGENT *grid[WORLD_X][WORLD_Y] = { NULL };

```
/* Verificar se numero de argumentos foi o correto */
if (argc != 8) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Modo de uso:\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\t%s -x -y -z -h -Z -H -t \n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

unsigned int WORLD_X = atoi(argv[1]);
unsigned int WORLD_Y = atoi(argv[2]);
int NHUMANS = atoi(argv[3]);
int NZOMBIES = atoi(argv[4]);
int NHUMANS_PLAY = atoi(argv[5]);
int NZOMBIES_PLAY = atoi(argv[6]);
int TURNS = atoi(argv[7]);

/* An instance of a SHOWWORLD world display. */
SHOWWORLD *sw = NULL;

/* A by-dimensional array of agent pointers, representing agents in a
   grid. In the final project the agent grid or world should be abstracted
   to specific world.c/world.h files, with new/destroy functions 
   All elements in this grid are initialized to NULL, i.e., they don't
   initially point to anything. */
AGENT *grid[WORLD_X][WORLD_Y] = { NULL };
```

A compilação do programa está a ser usado o seguinte comando *-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c99 -g* no ubunto

Comment: Você poderia instanciar na mão, na pior das ocasiões. Ou com `memset`, acho que da `string.h`. Dizer qual é o compilador _talvez_ tenha relevância, talvez um ou outro se comporte de maneira diferenciada para a inicialização de valores

Comment: Precisa de alocar memória na criação do array bidimensional